# How to fix coroutine lag when exporting to android from unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm working on a game that have some coroutines that make the character jump, attack etc, here is some example of the jumping coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator Jump()
{
    rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    moveHorizontal = 0f;
    rb.gravityScale = 0f;
    actualPlatform.actualPlatform = null;
    anim.SetBool("jumping", true);
    currentPlayerState = PlayerState.jump;
    float playerMoveY = transform.position.y + jumpHigh;
    float actualPlayerY = transform.position.y;

    while (transform.position.y <= playerMoveY)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, actualPlayerY);
        actualPlayerY = actualPlayerY + 0.1f;
        yield return null;
    }


    rb.gravityScale = 1f;
    dustEffectReady = true;
}
```

on desktop this coroutine works fine and fast but when I build the apk and try it, its slow and lagged, maybe its something about FPS? anyone know how to solve this? should I just use normal functions?

EDIT: I'm using this library to use the swipe method (the function that calls this coroutine) https://unity3d.college/2018/04/24/mobile-swipe-detection-in-unity3d/

then I'm calling it with this function:

```
private void SwipeDetector_OnSwipe(SwipeData data)
{
    if (data.Direction == SwipeDirection.Up && isGrounded && currentPlayerState == PlayerState.idle)
        StartCoroutine(Jump());
    else if (data.Direction == SwipeDirection.Down && currentPlayerState == PlayerState.idle)
        StartCoroutine(SlideDown());
    else if (data.Direction == SwipeDirection.Left && currentPlayerState == PlayerState.idle)
        StartCoroutine(weaponController.Attack());
    else if (data.Direction == SwipeDirection.Right && currentPlayerState == PlayerState.idle)
        StartCoroutine(weaponController.Attack());
}
```

Comment: Where's this called from? Are you sure it's the coroutine?

Comment: when I swipe i call the coroutine normaly     StartCoroutine(Jump());, and the game only lags when using coroutines, the whole game works fine, only the coroutine functions are lagged

Comment: Edit your question to include that code. Not just the line that says `StartCoroutine` but the entire class.

Comment: @Draco18s done, the code is pretty big but i posted the relevant information

Comment: Ok, I don't see anything from that context that would result in unexpected behavior (eg. starting the coroutine every frame). So I'm not sure.

Comment: Also when testing the game in unity remote 5 it works as expected, maybe its something about the build?